# Can a particle that obeys Maxwell Boltzmann statistics interact with Magnetic field?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, atomic-physics

I was studying partition function in statistical mechanics. When N-spin particles are placed in a magnetic field we get two energy values μB and -μB. So, I was wondering if particles follow M.B statistics, will there be any energy (as they are classical particles and do not have spin) ??

Answer (score 0):

If the particles are charged or have magnetic moment of some order (even if they have zero first-order magnetic moment, they can have magnetic quadrupole moment), then they will interact with magnetic field.

In case this interaction is described by the magnetic Lorentz force $q\mathbf v\times \mathbf B$, there is no change to energy and to partition function; magnetic Lorentz force can't do any work on the particle, it does not change kinetic energy of the particle.